# Hartl Rails tutorial ch. 5 doesn't load bootstrap automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, bootstrap-sass

At the point in Ch. 5 of the Hartl tutorial where he's showing off CSS/SCSS/Bootstrap styling for the first time (ch. 5.1.2), you're supposed to see the page transformed from an unstyled HTML page to a nifty styled page. But I wasn't seeing the change. It stayed unstyled.

I typed in the listings carefully (and even copied and pasted them from the website, just to be sure, after encountering this problem), tried switching to different gem version numbers (as other advice on similar problems said to do), etc.

Then I decided to insert in my `application.html.erb` layout the `<link>` to the Bootstrap CDN, as well as `<div class="bootstrap-fluid">` (which I'm glad I learned from FreeCodeCamp) and that fixed the problem:

```
  <head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      ...
    </div>
  </body>
```

Apparently I had done nothing wrong otherwise...my guess is that the bootstrap-sass gem (or some other gem) was not supplying this information correctly.

I'm concerned that if I've put this code in my layout, stuff might break later on. Like, it's *supposed* to work without what I added, right? Any ideas how to make it work the way Hartl wants it to work?

UPDATE: Ugh. Typo! It turns out that I had misnamed custom.css.scss to custom.css.cscc. Well, that'll do it!

The only reason the Bootstrap CDN link helped was that my layout made use of some Bootstrap. When I started adding custom CSS to custom.css.cscc (sic!) I knew the file wasn't even being read. Lesson learned...type even more carefully.

Comment: Have you tried getting in contact with him to ask? :)

Comment: The first thing you need to check when you have this kind of `Asset Pipeline` problems is, what does your application.css looks like? because if your html does not get style, maybe there is no style at all to be applied. You can do this at `http://localhost:3000/public/nameofthecssfile.css` where name of the css file can be the application.css or some specific stylesheet. Please update your answer. Including link rel stylesheet is not a real solution and the idea of having application.css is useful because it will incredibly improve your app performances in production. I ll give you more info

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. I've solved the problem...it was embarrassing. See above.